# I want to attach a heat sink to the inductors on my motherboard, which glue could I use?

Tags: temperature, heatsink, motherboard

If I wanted to attach a heat sink to the inductors on my motherboard, which glue could I use?

I have a Gigabyte A320M-S2H, this motherboard has heating problem when used with the AMD ZRyzen 7 2700X processor. I believe that only a heat sink would solve this problem.

[image]

If you search the internet, you will find that the vast majority of motherboard models for this processor already have heatsinks.

Here is an example:

[image]

Is the heatsink on the mosfets or on the inductors?

I found a good image to explain this problem

[image]

Here is my problem

[image]

My processor is throttling to 500 Mhz

Comment: The items you highlight are inductors, are they known for running hot on this board? The FETs are the 8-legged devices next to them.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't knowledge about electronic components

Comment: the FETs are going to be the offender here, the inductors are just passives, and in most cases have very little heat. However that doesn't mean that you can put an individual heatsink on each of them, as their R_ds changes based on temperature, whih you want to be the same for all

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could dissipate this heat? Because of this high temperature, the clock drops a lot.

Comment: This package for the FETs isn't really designed for dissipating heat from the case, the thermal resistance to a bracket clamped to the top of them carries far less heat than the thermal path to the copper in the PCB, which is how they're intended to cool. Obviously you can't do anything about that. Practically, a better case fan cooling the entire board might be the most effective option.

Comment: I don't see a good description of the real problem.  Throttling helps reduce power when load is small.'

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, I'm sorry but I did not understand what you mean

Comment: When those chokes (aka inductors) warm up they get more efficient. peak efficiency is somewhere well past 100C, cooling the chokes it going to cause heating elsewhere and increase power consumption,

Comment: those other boards have the heatsink on the mosfets.

Comment: I don't see a good description of the real problem. There is no spec nor validation of problem as conduction or convection with forced air, so why ask for a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might not solve your problem, but to answer your question:

> I want to attach a heat sink to the inductors on my motherboard, which glue could I use?

Since there is no feature to mechanically mount a heatsink, adhesives must be applied.
Thermally conductive epoxy does exist, but it is rather expensive. (eg: [3M TC-2810](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=%203M%20TC-2810))
More suitable would be thermally conductive dual side tape. (eg [3M 8810](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3m-tc/1-2-5-8810/3M10315-ND/2649860))

---

Back to your problem: You have one of the cheapest motherboards (€50*), and fitted the highest power Ryzen 7 processor (105 Watt). This is not the intended configuration of this motherboard, power throttling is to be expected.
I recommend going with the 65 Watt Ryzen chips for this motherboard.

**Only two boards are cheaper!*

Answer (score 0):

Hot components on the secondary (on-board) power supply is an indication of poor mainboard design and under-sized inductors, it is true. However, it is highly unlikely that this is the root cause of your problem, so cooling down the hot components is unlikely to solve your problem of CPU stability/throttling. In long term it might be worth, but not for your immediate CPU issue.

What you need to do is to deploy a better (bigger) heat sink on your CPU, preferably with heat pipe design, and make a quality thermal interface between the CPU and the heat sink, ensuring flatness of both surfaces (CPU and heat sink) and carefully applying high-quality thermal compound.